# HSQLDB: INSERT INTO ... (SELECT NULL, * FROM) leads to "duplicate column name"

Tags: sql, hsqldb

In HSQLDB, I have two `TEXT` tables, mapped to CSV files.  See project [CSV Cruncher](https://github.com/OndraZizka/csv-cruncher).

```
CREATE TEXT TABLE session_telephony_pins ( Op VARCHAR(4092), id ... )
```

I am trying to add a column to this "input" table, so that the result would have an unique ID for each table.

So this seems quite logical: Add that column, defined as a sequence,

```
CREATE TEXT TABLE output ( crunchCounter BIGINT
  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE crunchCounter PRIMARY KEY, op VARCHAR(4092), ... )
```

and then use null to let the DB select the value:

```
INSERT INTO output (SELECT NULL AS crunchCounter, * FROM apollo_session_occurrence)
-- I also tried withhout `AS ...`
```

However if fails with:

```
SQLSyntaxErrorException duplicate column name in derived table
```

Tables and column types:

```
* APOLLO_SESSION_OCCURRENCE
  - OP                           CHARACTER VARYING
  - SESSION_OCCURRENCE_ID        SMALLINT
  - SESSION_ID                   SMALLINT
  - START_TIME                   TIMESTAMP
  - END_TIME                     TIMESTAMP
  - UID                          UUID
* OUTPUT
  - CRUNCHCOUNTER                BIGINT
  - OP                           CHARACTER VARYING
  - SESSION_OCCURRENCE_ID        CHARACTER VARYING
  - SESSION_ID                   CHARACTER VARYING
  - START_TIME                   CHARACTER VARYING
  - END_TIME                     CHARACTER VARYING
  - UID                          CHARACTER VARYING
```

I think in MySQL this would work, but haven't tested.

The types should not be an issue. If I drop the `crunchCounter` column and just do `INSERT INTO output (SELECT * FROM apollo_session_occurrence)`, it works fine.

I could theoretically use `NEXT VALUE FOR crunchCounter` but that wouldn't change columns metadata. This happens when HSQLDB checks the metadata.

What's going on? And,

**How should I fill the `output` table with the unique column?**

Edit: Interestingly, it works well with other tables and specifically named result columns:

```
INSERT INTO output (SELECT NULL AS crunchCounter,  jobName, buildNumber, config, ar, arFile, deployDur, warmupDur, scale,
  CAST(warmupDur AS DOUBLE) / CAST(deployDur AS DOUBLE) AS warmupSlower
  FROM concat ORDER BY deployDur)

* CONCAT
 - JOBNAME                      CHARACTER VARYING
 - BUILDNUMBER                  SMALLINT
 - CONFIG                       CHARACTER VARYING
 - AR                           CHARACTER VARYING
 - ARFILE                       CHARACTER VARYING
 - DEPLOYDUR                    SMALLINT
 - WARMUPDUR                    SMALLINT
 - SCALE                        SMALLINT
* OUTPUT
 - CRUNCHCOUNTER                BIGINT
 - JOBNAME                      CHARACTER VARYING
 - BUILDNUMBER                  CHARACTER VARYING
 - CONFIG                       CHARACTER VARYING
 - AR                           CHARACTER VARYING
 - ARFILE                       CHARACTER VARYING
 - DEPLOYDUR                    CHARACTER VARYING
 - WARMUPDUR                    CHARACTER VARYING
 - SCALE                        CHARACTER VARYING
 - WARMUPSLOWER                 CHARACTER VARYING
```

Starts to look like a HSQLDB bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out. The problem is that HSQLDB expands the `*` in `SELECT 1 AS foo, * FROM myTable` into `foo, foo, myTable.col1, ...`.

That is IMO a bug.
Edit: Not a bug, but HSQLDB could give a better error message.

**The workaround:** Use qualified wildcard.

```
INSERT INTO output (SELECT NULL AS crunchCounter, 
        apollo_session_occurrence.* 
   FROM apollo_session_occurrence ...)
```

Comment: It is not a bug. Only `SELECT * FROM` is legal syntax. The HSQLDB has a bug trackter on SourceForge which is linked from http://hsqldb.org

Comment: Hi Fred! Thanks for chiming in. It's a legal syntax, but this is the first db i met that expands it to the result of the SELECT. Normally it expands to all columns coming from the FROM clause.   I'll file a bug/RFC and explain there.

Comment: In your case, it does not even expand the `*` when there is any other column. The error message for duplicate names is used, which is not exactly correct.

Comment: @fredt, sure, I am assuming what it does, I don't really know it. What should be the error message then?

Comment: I don't think an exact message is necessary to refer to this situation..

Comment: I still don't understand what's the issue then. It is a legal syntax, but HSQLDB throws an error? So where is the issue then if not in HSQLDB?

Comment: Legal syntax is defined by the SQL Standard and is followed by HSQLDB in this case.

Comment: I see what you mean now. No additional columns are allowed in `SELECT` if an unqualified `*` is used. Well, maybe HSQLDB could really give that exact sentence as an error, since other DBs allow it and HSQLDB tries to be nice to devs accustomed to other DBs.